# Printing from flash on MAC stretches?

Tags: flash, actionscript, printing

I have a flash movie which produces a certificate for participants in an online course.

It gets the `pageHeight`, `pageWidth` from the `printjob` then scales the certficate image to fit nicely in the middle.

This is working fine on windows and linux, but on the mac it is not behaving. It is chopping of the right and bottom edge of the certificate, I think because it's misreporting the page size - putting in some debugging information about the dimensions reports as expected - the same as on other platforms - but if I put two printouts on top of each other on a lightbox, the mac one is scaled up, mostly horizontally.

Anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure if this is true for particular versions of OSX or the flash player, but it turns out that anything that is not actually visible on the stage won't get printed on the mac.

The movie clip was being scaled up on printing - I wanted it to be able to print larger if the user had a larger printer - but it meant that some of the edges went past the stage boundaries. If I set a limit on the scale of the movieclip it seems to do what it should.

*(sigh)*